# Oracle: select records between two hours

Tags: oracle, date

Oracle 19c. I have a table with created_date column as DATE.

Can someone advise on how to select records from that table where created_date between hours of 9PM and 12PM within the same date.
So, for the data below, it will show 5 records.

Here is the sample of the data:

[image]

Comment: Do you mean 12am (midnight so a 3 hour window) or 12pm (noon so a 15 hour window)?  None of your data is between the hours of 9pm and 12am.  Are you looking for data between those hours on any day?  Or just on one day?  Is 1/11/2023 Jan 11 or November 1, 2023?

Comment: You are correct: 9 PM to 12 AM. I am using mm/dd/yyyy mask. I made changes to original post.

Comment: OK.  Are you looking for data between 9pm on January 19, 2023 and 12am on January 20, 2023?  Or are you looking for data on any day that happen to be between 9pm and 12am?

Comment: @epipko, 9PM and 12PM of continuous date or date doesn't matter. Only time must be between 9PM and 12PM.

Comment: I've modified original post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need period between 21 and 12, then you need all, that less then 12 and biger then 21....

In this case solution is very simple:

```
select to_char(created_date, 'dd.mm.yyyy HH24:mi:ss') created_date_str
from   mytable 
where  to_number(to_char(created_date, 'HH24')) >= 21
    or to_number(to_char(created_date, 'HH24')) <= 12
```

Or, if you need period between 00 and 12, then this case will be suitable:

```
select to_char(created_date, 'dd.mm.yyyy HH24:mi:ss') created_date_str
from   mytable 
where  to_number(to_char(created_date, 'HH24')) between 0 and 12
```

Also, you can check this in the live example: https://dbfiddle.uk/mZy-jn-D

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using this: to_char(created_date, 'HH24') between '21' and '23'

Comment: @epipko, so I hope you know difference between comparing string and number... I really recommend cast both parts to number and then compare them.